# What is a better way to get a even number?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

So I have been reading this book named: Eloquente JavaScript, and to be true somethings in this book seems quite complex. There was this challenge were I had to wright a function that showed true or false depending if the value was even or not. My version is quite shorter then the one from the book. What should be the best way of doing this? Also why did he do it like this?

**Eloquente JavaScript code:**

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return true;
  else if (n == 1)
    return false;
  else if (n < 0)
    return isEven(-n);
  else
    return isEven(n - 2);
}

console.log(isEven(50));
console.log(isEven(75));
console.log(isEven(-1));
```

**My own code:**

```
function even(num) {
      if (num % 2 == 0){
         return true;
      }
      else{
         return false ;
      }
  };

  console.log(even(17));
  console.log(even(10));
  console.log(even(-33));
  console.log(even(-40));
```

Comment: It was probably the chapter about recursion, otherwise nobody would implement it like this.

Comment: Yes it was, so it was just for showing? My version is the right one?

Comment: Textbooks often do things the hard way because they want to teach a specific language concept. It's true that your function is "better" (although `return num % 2 === 0` would be even better), but if the book wants you to learn about recursion or else ifs, doing it your way wouldn't have taught you those things.

Comment: @Juhana I get it thanks :) I never read books about languages so I din't know they did it for the context.

Answer (score -1):

```
function even(num) {
    return num % 2 === 0;
}
```

Comment: That was not really my question, I know I can do it this way, I just wanted to know why they din't.